# @ControllerAdvice not being called from external jar

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jar

I have a spring boot web application which takes in an external jar which contains `@ControllerAdvice`. When i run the application, no `@ExceptionHandler` method is invoked. However, when I take out the class from the external jar and back into the application. Everything works fine. This is my `@ControllerAdvice` class inside the external jar

```
import org.zalando.problem.Status;
import org.zalando.problem.violations.ConstraintViolationProblem;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionTranslator implements ProblemHandlingWithNoSecurity {
    private static final String VIOLATIONS = "violations";
    private static final String MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String ERROR_HTTP = "error.http.";

    public ExceptionTranslator() {
    }
    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleBadRequestAlertException(BadRequestAlertException ex, NativeWebRequest request) {
        return this.create(ex, request, HeaderUtil.createFailureAlert(ex.getApplicationName(), ex.getEntityName(), ex.getErrorKey(), ex.getMessage()));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleConcurrencyFailure(ConcurrencyFailureException ex, NativeWebRequest request) {
        Problem problem = Problem.builder().withStatus(Status.CONFLICT).with("message", "error.concurrencyFailure").build();
        return this.create(ex, problem, request);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provice your componentscan configuration?

Comment: check the component scan path like `com.app.*.**` is same as in external path where ExceptionTranslator is placed

Comment: @Muhammad Zaid `@ControllerAdvice will work from external jars`

Comment: @AshokKumarN my main class is annotated as `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.carbook",
        includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(ControllerAdvice.class))
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.carbook"})
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class BookingsServiceApplication {`

Comment: And the `ExceptionTranslator` is in `package com.carbook.api.errors;
`

Comment: use like this in main class basePackages = "com.carbook.*.**"

Comment: Tried it, but still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: If it's any help, when i copy the `@ControllerAdvice` class from external jar to inside my project it will give an exception. `ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'exceptionTranslator' for bean class [com.carbook.api.errors.ExceptionTranslator] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.carbook.bookings.advice.ExceptionTranslator]`

Comment: I'm presuming because of this exception, that spring-boot can access the `@ControllerAdvice` from inside jar. But the `@ExceptionHandler` method isn't invoked. Not sure if my assumption is correct though.